# non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method error message- what am I missing?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Application which had files uploaded to a upload folder on the web server. I am in the process of trying to figure out the code to download an uploaded file in the browser for retrieval and viewing. Right now the code  is as below (the download part from code examples on the internet)

```
public void FileDetailsToolbarClickHandler(Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.ClickEventArgs args)
{

    string path = null;
    string uploads = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\uploads");
    path = uploads + "\\" + SelectedFileName;

    if (args.Item.Text == "Delete")
    {
        //Code for Deleting goes here

        //UploadRef.Remove();


        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }

        FileDetailsService.FileDetailsDelete(SelectedFileId);            //NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/ServiceRequestNotes/servicerequestnoteadd");
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/ServiceRequests/serviceRequestsaddedit2/{Id}", forceLoad: true);


    }


    else
    {
        // its a download
        IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(uploads);
        IFileInfo fileinfo = provider.GetFileInfo(path + SelectedFileName);
        var readStream = fileinfo.CreateReadStream();
        var mimeType = "application/pdf";
       
       return File(readStream, mimeType, SelectedFileName);
    }

}
```

On the last statement I am a getting the following  error message

**non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method error message**

What am I missing or do I need to change or add to have the output from the readstream render to the browser?

The blazor application is a blazor server app not WASM. It does not make use of API controllers.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a void method.  You can't return anything at all.  Also, if you're trying to instantiate a File object, you'd have to use the `new` keyword.

Comment: I changed it fr om a void to a task, but the same error message occurs at the return File line at the end of  the code. I guess Im still not understanding the ins and outs  of System.Io and files. In the code above the file provider, the fileinfo, and the readstream all work and come up wi the expected values. It knows which file I want and where its located. But its the final return file command that is the problem. Sorry if I am dense here. With this being a blaxzor web app- how do I achieve the final step of having it rendered to the blazor web  page as a footer attachment?

Comment: Thanks for whatever additional help can be provided

Comment: I have the file upload and file delete all working just not the download

Comment: I'm a little confused.  If you want to display an image that's now on your server, why aren't you just using an `<img>` tag?

Comment: sorry - the files uploaded to server can be of any type ( ie doc ,xls, pdf etc).  I have a couple of examples  that make use of java interop and/or controllers that don't seem to have any trouble with the  return 'File' command- but in my blazor app so far  I have most of the functionality of the app including the uploading and deleting from the file system without the use of API controllers

Comment: As a follow up, i have decided to go another route- using a API controller- it avoids the above error